# Why do I have to "vote to undelete" my own answer that I deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, vote-to-undelete

1. I write an answer
2. I find out it's very similar to someone else's, just a minute late
3. I **delete** the answer
4. I realize I can still make valuable contribution
5. I edit the answer
6. I click **undelete**

At this point, why do I have to "vote to undelete" my own answer (that *I* deleted)?

**Note** the answer has received no up-votes prior to deletion.

Comment: But it did immediately get undeleted when you "voted" for undeletion, or didn't it?

Answer (score 3):

It's an artifact of the way the delete/undelete system seems to work under the hood.  It's not really a "vote" - as soon as you confirm, it will actually get undeleted right away.

Comment: well, that depends. Is it an accepted answer? Is it a question with 2+ answers, or answers that have 2+ upvotes?

Comment: @Jeff - I thought you couldn't delete accepted answers in the first place.  The question was about vote to *undelete* - are there more rules relating to undelete?

Comment: @Jeff Atwood, updated question. The answer received no up-votes prior to deletion.